# Not able to create kafka topics with desired partitions using Kafka Admin Client API

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka Admin client API's to create the topic. The topic is getting created, however the topic is getting created with 1 partition by default. The API is not honoring the configurable value provided. Not sure if I'm using it correctly.

Note: Topic creation is enabled at broker level. Also the topic is getting created, but it is getting created with partition 1.

```
NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic(TOPIC_NAME, 10, (short) 1);
        CreateTopicsResult createTopicsResult = null;
        try {
            createTopicsResult = KafkaAdminClient.create(getAdminProperties()).createTopics(Collections.singletonList(newTopic));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However I'm able to increase the partitions of earlier created topics using Kafka Admin Client API's

Comment: Did you disable auto topic creation on the broker? Does that topic already exist?

Comment: And you don't put consumer properties into admin client

Comment: Topic doesn't exist already and I'm just putting broker details in Admin properties.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Please show more configs and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this, without success, using the following code:

```java
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.CreateTopicsResult;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class AdminApiDemo {

    private static final String BOOTSRAP_SERVER = "localhost:9092";
    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "demoTopic";
    private static final int NUM_PARTITIONS = 3;
    private static final short NUM_REPLICAS = 1;

    private final AdminClient adminClient;

    private AdminApiDemo(Properties properties) {
        this.adminClient = KafkaAdminClient.create(properties);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSRAP_SERVER);

        new AdminApiDemo(properties).createTopic(TOPIC_NAME, NUM_PARTITIONS, NUM_REPLICAS);
    }

    private void createTopic(String topicName, int numPartitions, short numReplicas) {
        try {
            final NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic(topicName, numPartitions, numReplicas);
            final CreateTopicsResult result = adminClient.createTopics(Collections.singletonList(newTopic));
            result.values().get(topicName).get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

A `kafka-topics --describe` showed the following:

```sh
root@kafka:/# kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --topic demoTopic
Topic:demoTopic PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: demoTopic    Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
    Topic: demoTopic    Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
    Topic: demoTopic    Partition: 2    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
```

I thought, ok, what if the topic maybe exists before creation, but then again I got an `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'demoTopic' already exists.`, so that could not be your case either.

I know this is no "real" answer, that fixes anything, sorry for that. But I hope it helps, anyway. Maybe someone else can use this to reproduce it in his setting and "sees" the problem.

Comment: The issue will get reproduced if you remove final keyword from the code. I can now able to create partitions using your code. Not sure why the constraint of final keyword for this.

Comment: I couldn't actually think of any reason, why the final keyword should lead to this behaviour, so I testet it. I still got the same results, three partitions as in my previous test. Did you know, if you maybe changed something else in you test? Before each test, I removed everything, to start with a fresh Kafka setup.

Comment: As I thought, the byte code of the `createTopic` method is exactly the same, so the final modifier cannot be the reason.

Comment: My guess is that you're seeing a race condition between the call to `createTopics` and the automatic topic creation behavior when a topic is referenced.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call .get() on createTopicsResult to wait for a response to your query.
Try this code:
`createTopicsResult.values().get(TOPIC_NAME).get()`